# Convert date manipulation code to a function then apply it to multiple columns

Tags: pandas, function, dataframe, python-3.6

Let's say a given dataframe `df` contains two date type columns `start_date` and `end_date`, they both need to be manipulated with the code below:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].str.split('d').str[0].add('d')
df['date'] = df['date'].str.replace('Y', '-').str.replace('m', '-').str.replace('d', '')
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d', errors='coerce').dt.date
```

Just wonder how I can convert it to a function `date_manipulate` like this:

```
def date_manipulate(x):
    return ...
```

Then apply it to those two columns, thanks for your help.

```
df[['start_date', 'end_date']] = df[['start_date', 'end_date']].apply(date_manipulate)
```

Comment: check this https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `df['date']` for `x`, because [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) processing both columns like `Series`:

```
def date_manipulate(x):
    x = x.str.split('d').str[0].add('d')
    x = x.str.replace('Y', '-').str.replace('m', '-').str.replace('d', '')
    x = pd.to_datetime(x, format='%Y-%m-%d', errors='coerce').dt.date
    return x
```

Also is possible simplify code:

```
def date_manipulate(x):
    x = x.str.split('d').str[0].add('d')
    x = pd.to_datetime(x, format='%YY%mm%dd', errors='coerce').dt.date
    return x
```

Comment: It works, thank u. But I can't simplify by your second solution, I'm going to post a new question regarding this.